# How to keep a log of all urls browsed by means of programming?

Tags: browser, monitoring

I know a lot of *keyloggers and kids monitoring agents* out there. My question is how do I simply get to hold the list of urls the user browsed using that particular browser by means of `programming`? I am not interested in using any kind of keylogger or any other monitoring tools. Thanx a lot.

Comment: What have you tried already? what programming language are you looking to use? are you looking to write a browser extension or an auditing app?

Comment: I think I will be using jms to produce and consume messages from the history location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Programmatic methods will vary between browsers and operating systems but browsing history is often stored in an SQLite database.

For example, Chrome on Windows 7 stores its history in:

```
C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\History
```

You can programmatically access this `History` file using the SQLite API or interactively using an SQLite manager such as [SQLite Expert](http://www.sqliteexpert.com/).

It is wise to open it read-only or otherwise make sure Chrome is closed before accessing it.

The `visits` table is a good place to start.

Comment: +1 for SQLite part. One more question sir, do you mean I have to timely monitor this location?

Comment: I've only used Chrome's History database to analyse aged data, not in real time. You haven't specified your exact needs but if you want real-time or close to real-time monitoring then you would need to access the database frequently. That is, if Chrome updates it immediately - I haven't checked. Other browsers may handle things differently. I'm not aware of a single cross-browser, cross-platform solution.